# Slope in interaction strength vs mass for QCD axion

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, axion

The theory models of QCD axion, i.e. those who solve the strong CP problem, all have a prediction that follows a band with a slope in the space interaction strength vs. axion mass.

(1) What does cause this slope? Is there an intuitive way to understand it? Why it is not a blob for instance?

(2) If I am not mistaken the model prediction of QCD axion is a band because is the parameter space between the two prediction lines of DFSZ/KSVZ. If this is the case why it is assumed as convection this band for the theory prediction?

[image]